# How to pull changes of remote branch only for particular sub module?

Tags: git, maven, github, project, git-clone

I have a git hub repo that I have cloned in to my machine which in turn consists of different sub modules(different maven projects). Now, I want to work with only a particular sub module but on a different branch than the parent repository was cloned from. lets say the parent repository was cloned from D1 branch but this particular submodule has to be build/worked by pulling the changes from D2 branch.
Should I checkout D2 branch and pull only the changes for this particular submodule post `git clone` or is there some better way to do this?